# Add minutes contained in a column to a date

Tags: postgresql, carto

In CartoDB I want to add minutes contained in a column of data type number to a date.
e.g.

SELECT my_initial_date + 'xx minute'::INTERVAL as my_date FROM table

What is working is:

```
SELECT my_initial_date + '7 minute'::INTERVAL as my_date FROM table
```

This adds 7 minutes to each my_initial_date.
What I want to do is the same but with a variable number of minutes stored in another column, e.g.:

```
SELECT my_initial_date + 'column_name minute'::INTERVAL as my_date FROM table
```

This doesn't work in CartoDB! How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to CartoDB support here the correct answer:

```
SELECT my_initial_date +(column_name::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as my_date FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select "DepTime2", "FlightDate" || ' ' || "DepTime2"
,
Select TO_TIMESTAMP('20191001' || ' ' || '18:33','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') 
from DEP1."FactItinerary"
limit 10;
```

EXAMPLE:

```
Select TO_TIMESTAMP('20191001' || ' ' || '18:33','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')
```